# Is there an alternative to using UNION / UNION ALL when using varying JOIN statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up a view in SQL Server and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. The table in question is like an Changelog/Audit table, which records all the changes to the records, like the field changed, what the value was, what it was changed to, who changed it, and when.

The problem is the values are often codes, and to know what the change is it will need to be joined to a different table to see the text field. To know what table to join it to, you have to use the field name in the table. So far the only way I've seen to do this is through multiple SELECT statements with different joins and then UNION ALL. I'm not sure if there's a smarter way I could be doing this, as it seems pretty heavy impact.

If I didn't explain that well enough, this is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```
SELECT
    TICKETID,
    FIELDNAME,
    SO.TEXT AS OLD,
    SN.TEXT AS NEW,
    USER,
    DATE
FROM
    CHANGELOG C
INNER JOIN STATUS SO
    ON SO.STATUSID = C.OLD
INNER JOIN STATUS SN
    ON SN.STATUSID = C.NEW
WHERE
    FIELDNAME = 'STATUS'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    TICKETID,
    FIELDNAME,
    UO.TEXT AS OLD,
    UN.TEXT AS NEW,
    USER,
    DATE
FROM
    CHANGELOG C
INNER JOIN USER UO
    ON SO.USERID= C.OLD
INNER JOIN STATUS UN
    ON SN.USERID = C.NEW
WHERE
FIELDNAME = 'ASSIGNEDTOUSER'
```

This works for what I want, but there are 30+ fields I may have to join. The query is going to become very large, and doesn't seem intuitive. Any help is appreciated, and sorry if a question like this has been asked before.

Comment: No matter how you do this, it is going to be messy.  You might consider storing all the references in a single table, so you can use a single join for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could union all the reference tables together first, and then join once:

```
with ref as (
      select 'STATUS' as fieldname, statusid as refid, text
      from status
      union all
      select 'USER' as fieldname, userid, text
      from user
      union all
      . . .
    )
select c.ticketid, c.fieldname,
       ro.TEXT as OLD,
       rn.TEXT as NEW,
       c.user, c.date
from changelog c join
     ref ro
     on ro.refid = c.old and ro.fieldname = c.fieldname join
     ref rn
     on ro.refid = c.new and ro.fieldname = c.fieldname
```